# How can I get rid of an old HDD that my PC currenty relies on to boot?

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, grub, clonezilla

So, this was kind of interesting. I have Windows installed on a 500 Gb hard drive, and there's been an additional 80 Gb drive sitting inside my tower for a couple of years, collecting dust (I don't even have it assigned a drive letter in Windows).

I just bought a new SSD, which I want to eventually use as my new system drive (preliminary research has led me to guess I may want to use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to just clone my C:\ drive onto it; does that sound right?*), and earlier today I tried installing it where that old 80 Gb dinosaur had been. Then, to my surprise, when I turned my computer on I was greeted by an error message from GRUB.

I guess ages ago I must have installed some Linux distro (honestly, I don't even remember) and gone the dual-boot route, causing GRUB to be installed on the 80 Gb so that my PC has actually been booting from that drive ever since. Then I suppose I stopped using Linux on this machine and configured GRUB to just boot Windows directly. And then I just forgot all about it.

Given that I have no interest in dual-booting (for this particular PC, I'm just sticking with Windows) OR in keeping that 80 Gb drive around, what are my options? Ideally I want to be able to just have my computer boot from the drive where Windows is installed. Is there a simple "switch boot drive" option somewhere?

<sub>*This is obviously another question entirely; feel free not to answer it.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to restore your Windows MBR.  The easiest way is to boot from the Windows CD/DVD.

- Remove the 80 Gb harddrive
- Boot from Windows CD/DVD and choose the "Repair" option
- Choose the command prompt
- Run the two commands

  - bootrec /fixmbr
  - bootrec /fixboot

If you're running XP, you need to run the recovery console from the Windows XP CD.  At the command prompt, type: fixmbr

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's any way to access these commands *without* the original CD/DVD? I have no clue where mine is.

Comment: Get this live cd:  www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Comment: Use the utility MbrFix 1.3.  The commands can be found at www.sysint.no/nedlasting/mbrfix.htm.  The command you want is: MbrFix /drive <num> fixmbr